# Reinstall Ventura without internet, possible?

Tags: macos, recovery, ventura

Is it possible to re-install Ventura on an M1 mac without internet.

When I try I get the "Activate Mac" message. I even tried using a bootable installer with the assets added.

[image]

Comment: Is this a Mac you recently acquired?  [Activation normally only appears when it’s been previously locked](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208987)

Comment: Do you not have access to Wifi (or Ethernet) anywhere?

Comment: this is something interesting i'd love to know the answer to!
I doubt they'd be allowing an installation without internet anymore.

Comment: The installation process doesn't require internet, but the device must be activated before the install can proceed. This is to check for active Find My locks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mileage seems to vary here. I just tried installing macOS Ventura from USB (createinstallmedia) on a used Macbook Pro 13 M1 I got at work.

TL;DR **Installation of macOS Ventura from USB stick fails without Internet.**

Steps I performed:

- Hold Powerbutton for Boot Options
- Select USB stick with macOS Ventura
- Disk Utility -> Erase SSD -> New APFS partition to my liking (clean install)
- Reboot required for Erasing the SSD (Disk Utility requests Reboot)
- After reboot the Macbook boots into a Recovery kind of thing
- Macbook asking for Internet to unlock / activate (Find My) the Macbook
- **FIX** Used my iPhones Personal Hotspot
- Macbook is happy and reboots into Recovery installer (not Ventura from USB!)
- Shut Down again
- Boot while holding the power button -> Boot Options -> Select macOS Ventura
- Install macOS Ventura starts
- Accept license
- Installation starts
- Installation stops at around 42% saying it NEEDS Internet to continue and something about Software Updates (?!?)

This can be an issue if you are, like me, in an environment without any free WiFi or Ethernet. Our companies WiFi is some 802.11x WPA Business which requires much additional configuration (MSCHAPv2 anyone?) and can't be joined by a simple password (needs a mobileconfig file, like e.g. eduroam from university). These kind of WiFis cannot be joined during installation, as the needed parts of the OS are missing.

**Fix** Install with your iPhones Personal Hotspot, be sure to have a huge enough data plan and a phone charger nearby :)